# plus operator with quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript

Recently I saw a function in which arguments are surrounding with plus operator and quotes like this:

```
function foo(elemId, a, interval) {
   // Some logic here;
   // Basically some animation logic


   // Recursive
   var repeat = "foo('"+elemId+"',  '"+a+"', '"+interval+"')";    

   setTimeout(repeat, interval);

}
```

Here elemId is a string type, `a` and `interval` can be anything (take integer suppose).

What is the purpose of surrounding plus operator on both sides with a quotes?

Edit: I know that single plus operator before a string will convert it to number if it were a string like this `"33"` otherwise to `NaN`. But in this case, it must not be done to convert it to number because `elemId` here is just id of the element.

Edit 2: Why can't we directly pass function to setTimeout like this:
    `setTimeout(foo, interval);`

Comment: In this case it is string concatenation

Comment: Its to pass the vars back to `foo` when javascript calls `foo` again after `interval` milliseconds

Comment: It is string concatenation. The setTimeout will do an eval of repeat.

Comment: The plus operator isn't surrounded by quotes, the plus operator is between quoted strings.

Comment: Is it arguments surrounded by plus or string concatenation?

Comment: this question has to be a duplicate...

Comment: it's worth saying that this code is an example of really bad practice, that you should not be following.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is building a piece of JavaScript that will be `eval`ed by `setTimeout`. The JS includes a function call and arguments passed to it need to be string literals (i.e. quoted) to avoid them being treated as identifiers (i.e. variables).

This is not good practise though. It will break if any of the data includes quotes, and passing strings to be evaluated is inefficient (and can do unexpected things with scope).

The code should be written as:

```
setTimeout(function () { foo(elementId, a, interval); }, interval);
```

i.e. passing a function that calls `foo` with the variables being captured by the scope.

… or by using the three argument form (which isn't supported by Internet Explorer):

```
setTimeout(foo, interval, [elementId, a, interval]);
```

Comment: why we can't directly do `setTimeout(foo, interval)`; (foo without quotes) or `setTimeout(foo(elemId, a, interval), interval)`;

Comment: @ashish2expert — The former wouldn't pass `foo` any arguments, the latter would call `foo` **immediately** and pass its return value to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have explained, the pluses here are not to be read as part of the variables, they are simply there to concatenate a string. The principle is the same as the following:

```
var name = "ashish2expert";
var some_int = 5;

var concatenation = "This question was asked by " + name + " approximately " + some_int + " minutes ago.";

// Will result in
// "This question was wasked by ashish2expert approximately 5 minutes ago."
```

Answer (score -1):

Read it like this (spaces will make it easier):

```
var repeat = "foo('" + elemId + "',  '" + a + "', '" + interval + "')";
```

`setTimeout` expects a function name as string literal. The parameters to that function are being appended inline. The whole function call will be passed as a string literal to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout("foo('elem', '1', '2')", 2)
```

Where elemId = elem,  a = 1 and interval = 2

Comment: No. It will be `setTimeout("foo('elem',  '1', '2')", 2)`

Comment: Oh yes @Quentin ! Thanks. I missed it out completely, trying to type and post quickly. Thanks again, it was very important in the context.